# Everyday at the same time my website goes down for a few minutes

Tags: database, reports, query, maintenance

It gets put into maintenance mode. It has to be some type of job or module conflict or huge mysql query. I looked and there were no cron jobs running at that time. My new relic instance is saying that this are the process hogs at the time of outage.

```
Breakdown table
Category    Segment % Time  Avg calls
(per txn)   Avg 
time (ms)
WebTransaction  /pagecache/request/process  77.0    1.0 352
Database    Redis hget  11.8    54.6    54.4
Database    MySQL core_session update   2.8 0.533   12.7
Database    MySQL core_session insert   2.5 0.467   11.6
Database    MySQL other 0.8 3.0 3.7
Database    MySQL log_url insert    0.5 1.0 2.34
Database    Redis connect   0.5 2.0 2.14
Database    MySQL sales_flat_quote select   0.5 2.18    2.07
```

my reports say it's a module:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:1526:"#0 /var/www/mine/releases/20170630191905/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(848): Mage_Core_Model_App->throwStoreException()
#1 /var/www/mine/releases/20170630191905/app/Mage.php(353): Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore(NULL)
#2 /var/www/mine/releases/20170630191905/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Helper/Data.php(281): Mage::getStoreConfig('system/cron/err...')
#3 /var/www/mine/releases/20170630191905/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(260): Aoe_Scheduler_Helper_Data->sendErrorMail(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule), 'exception 'Mage...')
#4 /var/www/mine/releases/20170630191905/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(605): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->runNow(true)
#5 /var/www/mine/releases/20170630191905/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(39): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->process()
#6 /var/www/mine/releases/20170630191905/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /var/www/mine/releases/20170630191905/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#8 /var/www/mine/releases/20170630191905/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#9 /var/www/mine/releases/20170630191905/cron.php(78): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
```

I did recently truncate the log visitor url table and it seemed to shorten the outages. But based on the above stuff it appears there's a lot more going wrong with the DB and or the AOE module.

I know i'm not providing a whole lot of information but if anyone has any ideas please. Thanks in advance.

Data.php line 281

```
public function sendErrorMail(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule $schedule, $error)
{
    if (!Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT)) {
        return;
    }
```

schedule.php line 260

```
    Mage::helper('aoe_scheduler')->sendErrorMail($this, $e->__toString());
```

schedule.php line 605

```
public function process()
{
    if (!$this->canRun(false)) {
        return $this;
    }
    $this->runNow(!$this->isAlwaysTask());
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: The error is from the self module `Aoe/Scheduler`. You can focus on `Helper/Data.php` or `Model/Schedule.php` to debug.

Comment: check by disabling the Aoe scheduler  module from app/etc/modules folder... also check in backend is there any scheduled backup running or not.......

Comment: @PYYick, i had a look at those files and the lines they suggested in the report and pasted them above but nothing stands out to me.

Comment: @BabyinMagento, I don't really want to disable it because this is in a production environment.

Comment: @Singleton you need one demo site  that should be exact copy of your live site for your experiments.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento Possibly my caching that is bring the website down?

Comment: @Singleton disable the cace from backend and check in demo site.....